# Get current clicked item values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing item and its property list on template using django.
item have saveral property-
name, price, vendor etc.

i am showing these items by for loop. i am trying to edit item detail for this i need to send new/old values to jquery function.

my code looks like-

```
{% for i in item %}
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productID" id="productID" value={{i.productID}}>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productName" id="productName" value={{i.productName}}>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor" id="vendor" value={{i.vendor}}>
   </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
{% endfor %}
```

jquery-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var productid = $("#productID").val();
        var vendor = $("#vendor").val();
        var productname = $('#productName').val();
        console.log(productid)
        console.log(vendor)
        console.log(productname)
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working for me.
please help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID or things will not work as expected.

What I would do is get rid of the ID completely, and just wrap each element in some sort of container.  When the submit is clicked, find the `.closest` container, and use that as the jQuery [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to find the inputs with the name's that you care about.

```js
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var productid = $("[name='productID']", $item).val();
    var vendor = $("[name='vendor']", $item).val();
    var productname = $("[name='productName']", $item).val();
    console.log(productid)
    console.log(vendor)
    console.log(productname)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% for i in item %}
<div class="item">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productID" value={{i.productID}}>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productName" value={{i.productName}}>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor" value={{i.vendor}}>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but in my case i dont have same id. id's are different for each elements

Comment: No they aren't: `id="productID"  value={{i.productID}}` - they have a different *value* but the id is always "productID"

Comment: Exactly, Ids like productId for example - needs combining with i on each loop iteration to make a unique id

Comment: i am not getting how can i add diff product ids for each item , can you please help me

Comment: i also try to put diff id by - id="productID{{i.id}}", but it also was not working

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is because you're repeating the same `id` multiple times in the DOM. That is invalid HTML. To group elements with common behaviours use classes instead.

Then you can use DOM traversal from the clicked `button` to find the related `input` elements and read their values by using a combination of `closest()` and `find()`. Try this:

```js
$('.submit').click(function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('.container');
  var productid = $container.find(".productID").val();
  var vendor = $container.find(".vendor").val();
  var productname = $container.find('.productName').val();

  console.log(productid)
  console.log(vendor)
  console.log(productname)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control productID" name="productID" value="{{i.productID_1}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control productName" name="productName" value="{{i.productName_1}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control vendor" name="vendor" value="{{i.vendor_1}}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control productID" name="productID" value="{{i.productID_2}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control productName" name="productName" value="{{i.productName_2}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control vendor" name="vendor" value="{{i.vendor_2}}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Note that this adds one extra wrapping `div` element within your loop so that it's much easier to retrieve the related elements.

Comment: still getting values for first element only

Comment: In which case please edit a working example of the problem in to the question, as you can see from the example above using classes that this works fine.